# Does my simple website need gatsby-plugin-offline and/or gatsby-plugin-manifest?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Gatsby comes with `gatsby-plugin-offline` and `gatsby-plugin-manifest` as standard. I'm wondering if I need them for my projects, I build simple websites (portfolio/blog/brochure) so I don't care for them to be saveable for offline viewing, etc.

Are any crucial benefits (that I'm not understanding) to having them enabled in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gatsby-plugin-offline` is quite self-explanatory, you can remove them if you don't need that functionality.

Regarding [`gatsby-plugin-manifest`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-manifest/) could be more useful since adds (among other things) some PWA features like allowing the users to add your site to their home screen on most mobile browsers.

In addition, `gatsby-plugin-manifest` adds automated (or manual) favicon support for all devices and resolutions, cache busting, and manifest path-based localization.